Is the butterfly space contractible?
The butterfly space (also called the bow-tie space) is the closed upper half-plane $X=\mathbb R\times [0,\infty)$ topologized as follows.  Points above the $x$-axis have their usual Euclidean neighborhoods.  A local base for a point $p=\langle p_x,0\rangle\in H$ on the $x$ axis is formed by the "butterfly neighborhoods" $N_\varepsilon(p)$ for $\varepsilon>0$, where $N_\varepsilon(p)$ consists of $p$ together with all points $q=\langle q_x,q_y\rangle$ at distance less than $\varepsilon$ from $p$ and lying underneath the union of the two rays in $X$ that emanate from $p$ and have slopes $\varepsilon$ and $-\varepsilon$.  In formula, $$N_\varepsilon(p)=\{p\} \cup \{q\in X:\|q-p\|<\varepsilon\text{ and }q_y<\varepsilon|q_x-p_x|\}.$$

Note that the subspace $Y=$ strict upper half-plane has the usual Euclidean topology from $\mathbb R^2$ and the subspace $H=$ $x$-axis is homeomorphic to $\mathbb R$ with its Euclidean topology.
This space has many interesting properties.  For example it is not second countable, but has a countable network.  See https://dantopology.wordpress.com/2023/03/26/the-bow-tie-space/ for more.
Question: Is the butterfly space contractible?
That is, is the identity map on $X$ homotopic to a constant map?

At first I thought one could build a homotopy by first shrinking each vertical line to its point on the $x$-axis, and then go from there.  But that does not work because each point on the $x$-axis is isolated in its vertical line.

@DavidGao I had a similar idea.  But I don't think that works.  The problem is that the pasting of all these paths into a desired homotopy $X\times I\to X$ of the full space is not continuous at $\langle p,0\rangle\in X\times I$ for $p$ on the $x$-axis.

I don't think so.  $f(p,0)=p$.  So given a butterfly nbhd $N_\epsilon(p)$ around $p$, we should in particular find some small $\eta>0$ such that for all $q\in N_\eta(p)$ and all $t$ with $0\le t<\eta$, we have $f(q,t)\in N_\epsilon(p)$.  But that does not work.  If $q$ is sufficiently close to $p$ and to the left of it, $f(q,t)$ will be just above $p$, so not in the butterfly nbhd of $p$.

Ah, you’re right. I was only thinking about what happens to the right of $p$, not to the left.

Yep! Tricky stuff.  I am starting to think that maybe the space is not contractible?

Maybe this fixes it: instead of starting every paths at once, you start at the right-hand side. Say, at time $t$, let $p=(x,y)$ move at speed $\min{te^x,1}-1$ or something of the sort, so that whenever a point on the $x$-axis starts moving, nothing to its left has moved. Of course this requires infinite time, but you can force all points to stop moving after moving distance $1$, so that the limit at infinity works. Continuity at infinity should not be hard to verify, so this still contracts onto an upper half away from the $x$-axis.

Yeah, shouldn’t have deleted it. I thought it was hopeless, and then I thought of this possible fix… I suppose for context, here is a brief summary of my first attempt: the path starting at a point on $x$-axis, go along the tangent circle (to the $x$-axis) of radius $1$ for $90$ degrees, before going vertically up is continuous. These paths partition the space, so I had proposed $f: X \times [0, 1] \to X$ defined by letting every point move along their unique path for a time period of $1$, which contracts onto the Euclidean part of the space.

Yeah. I’m still not going to check all the details, especially now this has become even more complicated. We’ll see if someone else has time and is willing to go through the entire argument.

After my first (incorrect) clumsy attempt, I think I now have a proof that the answer is no. This answer takes the loop suggested in DanTheMan's answer, but uses a different argument to provide a formal proof that it is nontrivial.
Let $D$ be the open disc of radius $1$ centered at $(0,1)$. For each $x \in D$, consider the secant line $s_x$ passing through the origin and $x$, and note that $s_x$ intersects the boundary of $D$ at exactly one point besides the origin; call this point $p_x$.
Define $H:X \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ to be:
$$
H(x,t) = 
\begin{cases}
tp_x + (1-t)x \text{, if } x \in D \\
x \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$
Intuitively, $H$ moves each point in $D$ along its secant line from the origin until it hits $\partial D$.
Claim: $H$ is a strong deformation retraction from $X$ to $X - D$.
Proof of Claim: $H$ is clearly continuous on $X - (0,0)$ since on that space it is either constant or just a deformation retraction in the Euclidean topology.
We note that $H$ has a "speed limit", in the sense that $d(H(x,t), H(x,t')) < 2|t - t'|$, where $d$ is the standard Euclidean distance.
So we now consider the inverse image of a neighborhood $N = N_\epsilon\left((0,0)\right)$. Let $\eta = \frac{\epsilon}{4}$ and $N' = N_\eta\left((0,0)\right)$. Then if $H(x,t) \in N'$, clearly $H(x, t') \in N' \subset N$ for $0 < t' < t$, and we also have $H(x,t') \in N$ for $t < t' < t + \eta$ by our speed limit, since $x$ must travel away from the origin by at least $3\eta$ to leave $N$. Thus every point in the inverse image of $N$ has a neighborhood with image in $N$, so the inverse image of $N$ is open and thus $H$ is continuous. $\Box$
Consider the loop $L$ that travels once around the boundary of $D$. Since $H$ is a strong deformation retraction, if $L$ is nullhomotopic in $X$, it must be nullhomotopic in $X - D$. But since the topology on $X - D$ is strictly finer than the Euclidean topology on $X - D$, this means that this loop must also be contractible in the Euclidean topology, which we know to be false.
Thus, the circle centered at $(0,1)$ of radius $1$ is not nullhomotopic in $X$, so $X$ cannot be contractible.

Also, a variant of the above argument shows that any distinct horizontal translates of $\partial D$ are not homotopic to each other: Deformation retract away a small disc from the interior of each one.

Two basic questions (as I am kind of new to algebraic topology).  (1) You showed a little more, namely that the space is not simply connected, right? (2) It's nice to know that $X-D$ is a strong deformation retract of $X$.  But just a part of your construction shows that $X-D$ is a retract of $X$.  Would that be enough to conclude that the left and right sides of the loop $L$ are path-homotopic in $X-D$ (by composing a homotopy of paths in $X$ with that retraction), etc, and get the same conclusion?

Very nice argument! (+1)

@PatrickR 1) Yes this shows $X$ is not simply connected, though that shouldn't be surprising of a path-connected, non-contractible space that is "$2$-dimensional" (higher homotopy groups would be more pathological). The fundamental group actually appears to be huge (uncountably generated) and very complicated. 2) Yes, having a retraction would be enough, though I like the SDR as it shows that $X$ and $X - D$ are homotopy equivalent, and barely adds any complexity to the construction.

Not only is the space not contractible, it's not even simply connected! Intuitively, any path to the x-axis must approach it along a flattening trajectory from either the left or the right, and these two options are not homotopic. Rigorously:
Consider two paths $\gamma_0, \gamma_1:[0,1]\rightarrow X$ from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 0,1\rangle$ such that $\gamma_0(t)$ is to the left of the y-axis and $\gamma_1(t)$ is to the right for all $t\in (0,1)$.1 If the space is contractible, then it is simply connected, so there is a path homotopy from $\gamma_0$ to $\gamma_1$, i.e. a continuous function $H:[0,1]\times[0,1]\rightarrow X$ such that $H(0,t)=\gamma_0(t)$, $H(1,t)=\gamma_1(t)$, $H(a,0)=\langle 0,0\rangle$, and $H(a,1)=\langle 0,1\rangle$ for all $a,t\in [0,1]$. Then, by the intermediate value theorem (which applies as $X$ is finer than the topology given as a subspace of $\mathbb R^2$), for any $t$ there exists an $a$ such that $H(a,t)$ lies on the y-axis. Furthermore, by continuity there must exist a function $T:[0,1]\rightarrow[0,1]\times[0,1]$ such that $H\circ T(t)$ is a path from $\langle 0,0\rangle$ to $\langle 0,1\rangle$ whose image lies in  $\{0\}\times[0,\infty)$. This is a contradiction, however, as $\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$ is a clopen subset of that subspace. Thus, $\gamma_0$ and $\gamma_1$ are not path homotopic, and the space is not simply connected.
Edit: here's another way to think about the above. Morally, we can think about the homotopy as extending a map $f:S^1\rightarrow X$ from the circle (obtained by joining the two paths) to one from the disk $\tilde f:B^2\rightarrow X$ that equals $f$ on its boundary. (Indeed, the ability to always extend a map in this way gives an equivalent definition of simply connectedness.) As such extensions of loops into $\mathbb R$ must contain everything on the interior of the loop (this is essentially the Jordan curve theorem), the same must be true for the finer topology on $X$. This image contains lots of paths to $\langle 0,0\rangle$ that only intersect $N_\epsilon(\langle 0,0\rangle)$ at $\langle 0,0\rangle$, which are all discontinuous.
1 $\gamma_0(t)=\langle -\sin(\pi t),\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(\pi t))\rangle$ and $\gamma_1(t)=\langle \sin(\pi t),\frac{1}{2}(1-\cos(\pi t))\rangle$ suffice.

Nice idea, but could you expand on why the $T$ exists?

Yeah, very nice idea.  But the tricky part is to show the existence of the continuous map $T$.  If $Z$ denotes the $y$-axis, the inverse image $H^{-1}(Z)\subseteq[0,1]\times[0,1]$ could have isolated points and show all kinds of irregular behavior. It's not connected in general, and it's not clear there would be a continuous $T$ as desired.

Are you certain that two loops that each touch the $x$-axis at distinct unique points are homotopic? Simple horizontal sliding seems to me like it wouldn't be continuous.

I think @MartianInvader is right - horizontal translation in $X$ isn't homotopic to the identity, so the fundamental group is the free product of $\mathfrak{c}$ copies of $\mathbb{Z}$.

@MartianInvader Like you said, the homotopy between the two paths can't be horizontal sliding. But there could be a different homotopy somehow.  The goal is to derive a contradiction to show the two paths are not homotopic.

@Carmeister I think it's even more complex than that. Consider that loops can intersect the $x$-axis not only at points, but in intervals. And the "interval" loops can have non-trivial relations.

@DanTheMan The problem with your recent edit is that a path in the image does not necessarily correspond to a path in the domain.

@MartianInvader I know that. The idea is that all paths that do lie in the image of the disk are extremely restricted at that point, yet it must inherit a local connectivity from the disk. Your proof is better anyways, I just feel there must be some good way to tighten up my approach. Arbitrary continuous functions are slippery things though.

@PatrickR I can show that ${0,1}\times[0,1]$ must lie within one connected component of $H^{-1}(Z)$, but path-connectedness is of course harder. Perhaps somehow the former can be sufficient?

I think this works?
EDIT: This does not work. See the comments for details.
Let $H: \mathbb{R} \times [0,1] \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a strong deformation retraction from $\mathbb{R}$ to the point $0$. Then $H': X \times [0,1] \rightarrow X$ defined as $H'((x,y),t) = (H(x, t), y)$ should be a strong deformation retraction from $X$ to its $y$-axis.
We then define a homotopy $H''$ on the inclusion of the $y$-axis into $X$ which rotates the line segment from $(0,0)$ to $(0,1)$ counterclockwise around $(0,1)$ by a quarter-turn, keeping the rest of the $y$-axis fixed. I believe this should also be continuous, as there's no longer the concern about "points to the left" as we had in the comments.
Concatenating $H'$ with $H''$ gives us a homotopy from $X$ to an image in the strict upper half-plane which is constant on all points on the $y$-axis with $y \geq 1$, so we can now just pick one of those points and strong deformation retract to it from the strict upper half-plane (which has its usual topology). Concatenating that homotopy on to the other two gives us a strong deformation retraction of $X$ to a point, showing that $X$ is contractible.

The $x$-axis has the Euclidean topology, not the discrete topology.  But I agree that $H'$ is not continuous; specifically, $H'(\cdot,1)$ from $X$ to the $y$-axis is not continuous.  If $p=(0,0)$ is the origin point, $H'(p,1)=p$.  Given a butterfly nbhd $V$ of $p$ in $X$, $V$ intersects the $y$-axis only in the point $p$.  But it's impossible to find a nbhd $U$ of $p$ in $X$ such that $H'(U,1)\subseteq V$, because $U$ always contains points $q$ above the $x$-axis, hence $H'(q,1)\notin V$.

An easier way to see this: $X$ is connected, but the $y$-axis $Z$ with the subspace topology is not connected.  So no continuous map $H'(\cdot,1)$ from $X$ onto $Z$ is possible.

@DavidGao The $x$-axis is not discrete. The intersection of $N_\epsilon(p)$ with the $x$-axis has the form $(p_x -\epsilon, p_x +\epsilon) \times {0}$.

@PaulFrost Oh, you’re right. I have misunderstood the definition. It seems I’ve just been making blunders after blunders about this elusive butterfly… I guess this means I really should head to bed now.
